# Trouble choosing names from dropdown options

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written some code in python in combination with selenium to select few options from three different dropdown boxes to reach the destination page. First off the browser is needed to click on a link in the first page to reach the page where dropdown item options are located. My script can click on the first page link but when it comes to choose the item from dropdown options then it fails to do that.

Site address [URL](https://www.anthem.com/health-insurance/provider-directory/searchcriteria)

The link titled `Search by Selecting a Plan or Network` available in the first page (when clicked) leads to the second page where dropdown options can be found.

Options I wanna choose from three different dropdowns (from second page):

1. Medical
2. Arizona
3. All plans/networks

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("use_above_link")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "lnkGuestPlanSearch"))).click()

Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$MainContent$maincontent$pfSearchMain$pfSelfPlanSelection$ddlPlanC')).select_by_visible_text('Medical')
Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$MainContent$maincontent$pfSearchMain$pfSelfPlanSelection$ddlState')).select_by_visible_text('Arizona')
Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$MainContent$maincontent$pfSearchMain$pfSelfPlanSelection$ddlPlanN')).select_by_visible_text('All plans/networks')

driver.quit()
```

Elements within which dropdown options are embedded:

```
</select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single pf-field-320-30" style="width: 0px;" title="" id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_ddlPlanC_chosen"><a class="chosen-single"><span tabindex="0">Enter or select type of care</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_ddlPlanC_chosen_input" type="text" autocomplete="off" title="auto"></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div></div>
    </div>

    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_divMedicalCareText" style="display:none">
       <table class="AlertBox" style="width:320px"><tbody><tr>
         <td class="AlertIcon"> <img alt="Find more information about Behavioural Health Providers" src="https://www.providerfinder.anthem.com/images/ProviderFinder/SearchResults/15_Info.png"></td>
         <td class="AlertBoxText" style="width:298px">Providers for Behavioral Health &amp; Substance Use Disorder Services are listed under Medical Care.</td></tr>
      </tbody></table> 
    </div>

    <div id="divState" class="paddingtop35 paddingbottom20" style="display: block;">
    <div class="headerstyle-item">
        <label for="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_ddlState_chosen_input" id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_Label1">What state do you want to search in?</label>
    </div>
    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$maincontent$pfSearchMain$pfSelfPlanSelection$ddlState" id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_ddlState" tabindex="0" class="pf-field" aria-labelledby="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelectPlanUnkwn_Label1" disabled="" style="display: none;">
    <option value="Enter or select a state">Enter or select a state</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>

<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single pf-field-320-30 chosen-disabled" style="width: 0px;" title="" id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_ddlState_chosen"><a class="chosen-single"><span tabindex="0">Enter or select a state</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_ddlState_chosen_input" type="text" autocomplete="off" title="auto" disabled=""></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="headerstyle-item paddingtop35" id="divPlanName">
            <label for="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_ddlPlanN_chosen_input" id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_Label6">Select a plan/network</label>
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_divPlanFocus" class="paddingbottom20">
        <select name="ctl00$MainContent$maincontent$pfSearchMain$pfSelfPlanSelection$ddlPlanN" id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_ddlPlanN" class="pf-field" aria-labelledby="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfPlanSelection_Label2" disabled="" style="display: none;"><option value="">Select a plan/network</option></select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single pf-field-320-30 chosen-disabled" style="width: 0px;" title="" id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_ddlPlanN_chosen"><a class="chosen-single"><span tabindex="0">Select a plan/network</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_ddlPlanN_chosen_input" type="text" autocomplete="off" title="auto" disabled=""></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="paddingtop50 paddingbottom50">
        <span>
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$maincontent$pfSearchMain$pfSelfPlanSelection$btnPlanCancel" value="Cancel" id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_btnPlanCancel" class="secondaryButton buttonwidth150">
        </span>
          <span>
           <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$maincontent$pfSearchMain$pfSelfPlanSelection$btnPlanContinue" value="Continue" id="ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_pfSearchMain_pfSelfPlanSelection_btnPlanContinue" class="primaryButton buttonwidth150">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Btw, when clicking on the first page link, it is necessary to wait few seconds so that the first page can load it's content.

Comment: you can try with simple click on dropdown and click on listed options may works. no need to use select class as it is hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that you're trying to handle wrong elements. Those `select` nodes are not what you actually need. You can do, for example,

```
type_of_care = driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$MainContent$maincontent$pfSearchMain$pfSelfPlanSelection$ddlPlanC')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display="block";', type_of_care)
```

to see that it's totally different drop-down

Try below solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.anthem.com/health-insurance/provider-directory/searchcriteria")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "lnkGuestPlanSearch"))).click()

type_of_care = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Enter or select type of care')))
type_of_care.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li[.="Medical"]'))).click()

state = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Enter or select a state')))
state.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li[.="Arizona"]'))).click()

network_plan = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Select a plan/network')))
network_plan.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li[.="All plans/networks"]'))).click()
```

Comment: The best selenium guru I've ever come across in my entire life @ sir Andersson. Although I didn't execute your script I'm sure it will lead me to the right direction. I've two questions on this: 1. why my select option failed? 2. As the first page (when opened) takes a lot of time to display it's content, sometimes browser fails to move on. Any idea for that, i meant, should I increase the waiting time or something? Very grateful to you sir and once again thanks a lot.

Comment: 1. The `select` nodes are hidden. It seem that this is how developer initially wanted drop-down to look like, but then it was re-designed and redundant code wasn't removed... or maybe not :) I'm not sure why those selects still present in DOM... 2. I cannot reproduce this issue. Can you share exception you get in this case?

Comment: No way, It did work like charm. Btw, the loading thing was happening perhaps at my end.